# Copying files to a mapped drive while user is not logged in (scheduled task)

Tags: c#, file, io, copy, console-application

I have a job that needs to connect to two fileshares and copy some files for a data feed.

The source server is on our domain's network, and that works fine. The remote server, however, chokes on me and throws a "Could not find part of the path" error. I should add the destination server lives in a different domain than my source server.

The source and destination paths are read out of my app.config file.

I thought persistently mapping a drive would work, but since this is a scheduled task, that doesn't seem to work. I thought about using NET USE, but that doesn't seem to like taking a username and password.

The really weird thing - if I double click on the job while I'm logged into the machine, it'll run successfully.

Sample code:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(srcPath);

        try
        {

            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                if(!(fi.Name.Contains("_desc")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name + System.Environment.NewLine);
                    File.Copy(fi.FullName, destPath + fi.Name, true);
                    fi.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

Apparently this isn't as simple as copying the files over. Any suggestions on mapping a drive with credentials in C# 4.0?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to use a batch file called from the console application that maps the drive while the program is running. I'll know for sure whether that works in the morning.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/177124/map-a-network-space-to-a-windows-drive-in-a-scheduled-job-script

Comment: So, this console application sits and runs and executes the provided code based on some schedule?  Or are you running this console application with something else that manages the schedule?

Comment: Peter, yes, I'm executing the program through Windows scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally wound up doing was mapping the drive in a batch file called by my program. I just launch a `NET USE` command and pause for a few seconds for the mapping to complete.

It looks like while the user is logged out, there's no context around mapped drives.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into a proper file transfer protocol, like FTP.

Assuming that's out of the question, try using a UNC path like `\\servername\path\file.txt`.  You will still need credentials, but assuming that the account running the application has those permissions you should be fine.  Given that you mention a web.config file, I am guessing that would be an ASP.NET application, and therefore I mean the account that runs the Application Pool in IIS.  See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Comment: You were close - it's actually a Windows console application running as a scheduled task.